# explicitly declaring inline functions signatures

Tags: f#

consider this code

```
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices


[<Extension>]
type Foo = 
    [<Extension>]
    static member inline classID (any : ^T) : ^U = 
        (^T : (member classID : Unit -> ^U) any)
    [<Extension>]
    static member inline parent (any : ^T) : ^U = 
        (^T : (member parent : Unit -> ^U) any)

let inline foo (tx : _) =
    tx.classID() + "!" + tx.parent().classID()
```

the first question is, what IS the signature of foo?

my intellisense says its

```
'a -> string (requires member classID and member parent and member classID)
```

which to be fair, is at best vague as there are 2 implicit type parameters involved here and it doesnt specify which type requires which member, but that may be a tooling issue.

Is it possible to write an explicit signature for this finction e.g. like this:

```
let bar : 'a -> string = 
    fun _ -> ""
```

i.e.

```
let [var] : [signature] = 
   fun [param] -> [result]
```

what would [signature] for foo?

(there will be an additional question about extracting this signature at run time, but I'll leave that as a seperate question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would write `foo` with explicit type annotations:

```ml
let inline foo (tx : ^T
    when ^T : (member classID : unit -> string)
    and ^T : (member parent : unit -> ^U)
    and ^U : (member classID : unit -> string)) : string =
    tx.classID() + "!" + tx.parent().classID()
```

So, in theory, I suppose its signature is:

```ml
(^T
    when ^T : (member classID : unit -> string)
    and ^T : (member parent : unit -> ^U)
    and ^U : (member classID : unit -> string)) -> string
```

It's not possible to write an explicit signature for `bar` because `bar` would have to be inline, and only functions can be inline, so `bar` itself is impossible.

This is why I wrote "in theory" above. You can't use `foo`'s signature in actual F# code, so does it really have a signature at all? The root problem here is that statically resolved type parameters in F# are (IMHO) very flaky and poorly documented, so it's hard to know for sure if there is any truly correct answer to your question.

Comment: sorry, maybe my bar thing wasnt clear, its just meant to demonstrate how to write a function with an explicit signature. I like your made up signature, i came to F# via haskell, so the idea you have functions that you can't write the signature for, for me is odd (i.e. not good).

Comment: I agree. I think SRTP’s are OK in some limited cases, but are a poor substitute for Haskell type classes.

Comment: try the next question....which is about deriving the signature at runtime