# how to infer type signature of inline function (method)

Tags: f#

so given this

open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

```
[<Extension>]
type Foo = 
    [<Extension>]
    static member inline classID (any : ^T) : ^U = 
        (^T : (member classID : Unit -> ^U) any)
    [<Extension>]
    static member inline parent (any : ^T) : ^U = 
        (^T : (member parent : Unit -> ^U) any)

let inline foo (tx : _) =
    tx.classID() + "!" + tx.parent().classID()
```

as per this answer [explicitly declaring inline functions signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71987340/explicitly-declaring-inline-functions-signatures)

we can sort of informally say that the signature of foo is

```
(^T
    when ^T : (member classID : unit -> string)
    and ^T : (member parent : unit -> ^U)
    and ^U : (member classID : unit -> string)) -> string
```

can i deduce this signature at run time?

i.e. something like this

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection
let funString o =
    let rec loop nested t =
        if FSharpType.IsTuple t then
            FSharpType.GetTupleElements t
            |> Array.map (loop true)
            |> String.concat " * "
        elif FSharpType.IsFunction t then
            let fs = if nested then sprintf "(%s -> %s)" else sprintf "%s -> %s"
            let domain, range = FSharpType.GetFunctionElements t
            fs (loop true domain) (loop false range)
        else
            t.FullName
    loop false (o.GetType())

let foo2 (x: 'a) = x
let y = funString foo2
```

gives

```
System.object -> System.object
```

ok, thats not quite right, but it derives something believable. If i try to do this with 'foo' the inline function it wont compile.

```
let z = funString foo
```

error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   FS0071  Type constraint mismatch when applying the default type 'obj' for a type inference variable. The type 'obj' does not support the operator 'classID' Consider adding further type constraints
```

this sort of makes sense, its basically saying it can't resolve what foo is at compile time but is there a way to do it?

Ideally this would be somethnig that i would do at runtime in the assembly that contains foo, but that looks unlikely, so i'd be happy to load an assembly with such inline methods and infer them.

Comment: SRTPs don't exist at runtime

Comment: can i for example, write code that loads the binary that contains this inline function? for example, the F# compiler must do this?

Comment: System.Reflection.PortableExecutable and System.Reflection.Metadata seem to allow me to open the assembly up and take a look, but its far from obvious whats going on

Comment: STRP-typed functions do not exist at runtime, they're inlined at call sites. That's what `inline` means. This is necessary because .NET runtime does not support this kind of constraints.

Comment: i've amended the question, forget the runtime issue, the requirement is to infer signatures of inline methods potentially in another assembly - thus the reference to System,Reflection.Metadata which is about reading metadata from non executing assemblies